# Docker for Mac: build proxy settings when using remote context

Tags: docker, macos, proxy, docker-build, docker-for-mac

I have a Linux system where I run docker. This system can only access the internet via corporate proxy.

For `docker run` I had to set the proxy config in my `~/.docker/config.json`:

```json
{
  "proxies": {
    "default": {
      "httpProxy": "...",
      "httpsProxy": "...",
      "noProxy": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

To use proxy in `docker build` I had to set env vars in `/etc/sysconfig/docker`:

```
HTTP_PROXY="..."
HTTPS_PROXY="..."
NO_PROXY="..."
```

This system works fine and I can run `docker run` and `docker build`, both using the proxy settings.

Now I want to run my local docker on MacOS against this remote machine via `docker context`.

I created a context that connects via ssh to the remote host:

```bash
docker context create remote \
   --description "remote execution" \
   --docker "host=ssh://docker.remote"
```

I also set the proxy settings in my local `~/.docker/config.json`:

```json
{
  "proxies": {
    "remote": {
      "httpProxy": "...",
      "httpsProxy": "...",
      "noProxy": "..."
    }
  }
}
```

A `docker info` shows the proxy is used and for `docker run` that also is true and I can access the internet from within containers.

Any attempt to access the internet though fails when calling `docker build`.

Is there some other file I need to change, just like the sysconfig file on linux?

---

I do have an ugly workaround now. I found that setting the proxy via `--build-arg` acutally works. To not always have to set the `--build-arg`s manually, I added an override for the docker command in my `.bashrc`. Ugly but working.

```bash
function docker {
  if [ "$1" == "build" ] && [ "$#" -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Building with proxy!"
    /usr/local/bin/docker "$@" \
      --build-arg http_proxy="..." \
      --build-arg https_proxy="..." \
      --build-arg no_proxy="..."
  else
    /usr/local/bin/docker "$@"
  fi
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems an issue with docker backward compatibility with older versions settings, I've tried every single solution online for setting a proxy that affects `docker build` command, the only thing that worked for me:

1. Open **Troubleshoot** settings (bug button) from Docker Desktop

[image: troubleshoot button]

2. **Clean/Purge data**

[image: clean purge data button]

4. Optionally **Reset to factory defaults**

[image: Reset to factory defaults]

5. Purge every thing, **NOTE** that you will lose all your local images, containers, volumes.
6. After docker restarts set the proxy from Docker Desktop in `Settings > Resources > Proxies`, and it will take effect.

### But I can't risk losing my data

the tedious solution unfortunately is setting `HTTP_PROXY` & `HTTPS_PROXY` env variables for every terminal session/process before executing docker commands:

Mac / Linux:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=...
export HTTPS_PROXY=...
```

Windows:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=...
set HTTPS_PROXY=...
```